# Can't install Ruby Gems - gives a zlib error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

---

Whenever I try and install any ruby gem (trying to install rails), I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: update (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I have tried everything I can think of; reinstalling ruby, trying different ruby versions, etc., but I keep getting this error.

I am currently using Ruby Version 2.3.1, and I am on mac os x 10.11 El Capitan. I am trying to install the rails gem on my system so that I can use it in all my projects.

Comment: Are you using a Ruby package manager like RVM?

Comment: Yes I am using rvm

Comment: could you write down the command before you got that error?

Answer (score 1):

Install zlib in your machine

```
rvm get head
rvm pkg remove
rvm requirements run force
rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p374
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you missed `zlib` package if you are using `rvm`.
https://rvm.io/packages/zlib/

**Update**:

I have two options, you can try one of them.

*Option1*:

Copy and paste this command to your console:

```
rvm pkg install zlib
rvm autolibs rvm_pkg
```

*Option* 2:

You need to install the `zlib` development headers.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then `reinstall` your `gem`.

Answer (score 0):

If installing gems you used:

*sudo gem install nameOftheGem*

problem could be that you only use *sudo* if the stack was installed as root, so try the same as above without *sudo*.